# Where does one look when debugging WP site with 'invalid range' compilation error?

Tags: php, wordpress

I will ask your patience with this post -- I'm not a WP programmer, more of a Javascript full-stack guy, but a friend asked me why she is getting the following error on many pages of her WP gallery site (also see attached pic)

```
Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset
```

I did a search of Stack Overflow, but the answers I saw seem to be for those who have programmed the PHP themselves.  Here I am working with an existing site that relies on pre-built galleries, etc.

A page where this is occurring is http://pixiealexander.com/beach-paintings/.  The problem seems to be intermittent -- it seems to disappear on re-load.   I have been poking around but, ahem, know very little about WP, and I don't know where to begin to start.  It would seem she is using WP 5, and the "NextGen" gallery....

I realise this is not a typical Stack Overflow question, but, as said, I beg your indulgence and ask you not to down-vote me, as I'm simply trying to help a friend...I

[image]

Comment: are you using the latest version of the plugin?

Comment: I'll have to see...

Answer (score 1):

It most likely mean that inside one of your character classes [a-z] or maybe [a-z0-9] you have hyphen '-' that doesn't really relate to a range of characters like 0-9 and a-z do, so you need to look at that line and escape the offending hyphen that isn't really a true representation of a range of characters, like so '\-', This is a known problem that effects some versions of PHP(s) PCRE